# RNN Keras model for NLP takes lot of time while training with no decrease in validation loss

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have built an RNN model for entity recognition. I used BERT embedding and then processed the results through a RNN Model. However, while training the model for 5 epochs, each epoch seems to take about 2 hours. Also, the validation loss does not seem to decrease at all.

I am running the process on a RTX 2080 GPU. I have tried manipulating the model but does not improve the model. The dataset I have is of about 400000 sentences.

This is my model:

```
def build_model(max_seq_length, n_tags): 
    in_id = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_ids")
    in_mask = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_masks")
    in_segment = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="segment_ids")

    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]   
    bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3, pooling="first")(bert_inputs)
    x = RepeatVector(max_seq_length)(bert_output)
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_units, return_sequences=True,
                           recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(x)
    x_rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_units, return_sequences=True,
                               recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(x)
    x = add([x, x_rnn])  # residual connection to the first biLSTM
    pred = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(x)

    model = Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

This is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_ids (InputLayer)          (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_masks (InputLayer)        (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
segment_ids (InputLayer)        (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bert_layer_3 (BertLayer)        ((None, 30), 768)    110104890   input_ids[0][0]                  
                                                                 input_masks[0][0]                
                                                                 segment_ids[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_2 (RepeatVector)  ((None, 30), 30, 768 0           bert_layer_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirectional) ((None, 30), 30, 200 695200      repeat_vector_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirectional) ((None, 30), 30, 200 240800      bidirectional_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     ((None, 30), 30, 200 0           bidirectional_2[0][0]            
                                                                 bidirectional_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDistrib ((None, 30), 30, 3)  603         add_1[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 111,041,493
Trainable params: 22,790,811
Non-trainable params: 88,250,682
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Logs:

```
 32336/445607 [=>............................] - ETA: 2:12:59 - loss: 0.3469 - acc: 0.9068
 32352/445607 [=>............................] - ETA: 2:12:58 - loss: 0.3469 - acc: 0.9068
 32368/445607 [=>............................] - ETA: 2:12:58 - loss: 0.3469 - acc: 0.9068
```

Can you help me find out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you please display your training logs? What is the batchsize? If it's small - this  may be the case.

Comment: Question updated @Dilshat

Comment: Did you manage to get the Bert Embedding Layer working? [Borg1903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8703627/borg1903)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bert for embedding, the output shape should be `(None, 30, 768)`. But your Bert model is returning a `(None, 768)` tensor, then you used `RepeatVector` to duplicate it. I guess you are extracting `[CLS]` output from Bert. Please extract the right layer from Bert model.

And the reason why the trianing takes so long is just because for every epoch you need to pass all your data through the huge bert model, even you are freezing most of the layers.

Comment: aaah! **compute_output_shape** in BertLayer was returning `inputshape[0][0]` instead of `input[0]`. Now the BERT layer returns `((None, 30), 768)` and not `(None, 30 , 768)`. How do I get around this? Because now, after using RepeatVector it gives `((None, 30), 30, 768)`.

Comment: I don't think you need the `RepeatVector` layer anymore. Because `(None, 30, 768)` is the shape you want, i.e. for each of 30 tokens, it is giving you a 768 dim representation.

Comment: I have no idea how your `BertLayer` look like. So I have no idea what is happening inside. However, you might take a look at [keras-bert](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert) project.

Comment: But after the BertLayer it gives me `((None, 30), 768)` and not `(None, 30, 768)`.

Comment: @Borg1903 did you manage to get the Bert Embedding Layer working? [Borg1903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8703627/borg1903)